# Getting NaN while calculating Total

Tags: jquery, product, invoice, calculated-field

I am trying to calculate Product price with quantity and then show the total but When I calculate I get result as NaN

Here is the code

```
$('button').click(function() {
   var total = 0;

   $('#mineraltable tbody tr').each(function(index) {

      var price = parseInt($(this).find('.price').text());
      var quantity = parseInt($(this).find('.quantity input').val());
      var value = $(this).find('.value');
      var subTotal = price * quantity;

      value.text(subTotal);
      total = total + subTotal;
   });

   $('#result').text('Your value is: '+ total);
      console.log(total);
   });
```

Your value is: NaN

Comment: That means whatever value you are trying to parse as integer, cannot be parsed as integer. We have no idea which values you are trying to parse...

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal If `parseInt()` returns NaN, how can it be different using `parseFloat()`?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal nope, not working same result.

Comment: @A.Wolff The values are from database $row[price]

Comment: Can you share what are the types of data that might be present in `price` and `quantity input` ?

Comment: So now we still have no idea what are `$row[price]` values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not sure of the data that might be present in these fields, you can use [IsNaN()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) and check wheather the text is number or not.

```
$('button').click(function() {
                  var total = 0;

                  $('#mineraltable tbody tr').each(function(index) {
                  var price = 0 , quantity = 0;

                  price = parseInt($(this).find('.price').text());
                  quantity = parseInt($(this).find('.quantity input').val());

                 //check for NaN
                  price = isNaN(price) ? 0 : price;
                  quantity = isNaN(quantity) ? 0 : quantity;

                  var value = $(this).find('.value');
                  var subTotal = price * quantity;

                  value.text(subTotal);
                  total = total + subTotal;
                });

                $('#result').text('Your value is: '+ total);
                console.log(total);

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your values you may be passing any non numeric value in parseInt function.